# Finding injective map from a rational coordinate to natural number

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, natural-numbers

Let $(p, q)$ be a rational coordinate in range $[0,1] \times [0 , 1]$. My goal is to show that for each $(p,q)$, I can find a unique natural number $n$.

My current approach is to find an injective function which takes $(p, q)$ to a natural number.
Since $p$ and $q$ are rational, there exist unique representation by fractions. So that

$p = \frac{a}{b}$ and $q = \frac{c}{d}$ where the ordered set $(a,b, c,d)$ is unique for each $(p,q)$.

Then the natural number $n$ which is the concatenation of $(a,b, c,d)$ is also unique. For example, if $(a, b, ,c,d) = (3, 82, 4, 9)$, $n = 38249$. As the ordered set only contains natural numbers, the concatenation should be possible.

I don't know if this is a valid way to show the existence of the unique natural for each coordinate as I can not show that the concatenation of natural numbers are allowed mathematically. Is there any other way to show that?

Comment: If you only want to show the existence of such a function, you can use the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and so is $\mathbb{Q} \cap \left[ 0, 1 \right]$. Thus, there is a bijection (and in particular an injection) from $\mathbb{Q} \cap \left[ 0, 1 \right]$ to $\mathbb{N}$. Then, $\mathbb{Q} \cap \left( \left[ 0, 1 \right] \times \left[ 0, 1 \right] \right)$ is bijective with $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$. Finally, since $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is bijective to $\mathbb{N}$, using composition of functions, you can conclude the result.

Comment: Your example is not valid since $(3/82, 4/9)$ has the same image as $(3/8, 2/49)$. So it is not injective. See my answer to have an injective function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** Consider the map $f : (\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]) \times (\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1])  \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ defined by
$$f \left(\frac{a}{b}, \frac{c}{d} \right) \mapsto 2^a3^b5^c7^d$$